# "Incorrect Content-Type: image/png" when trying to upload png with Ajax to Asp.net Core server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, image-uploading

Hi I'm trying to upload arbitrary files with Ajax to my Asp.net Core server using the following code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Provider/Image/' + guid,  
            type: "POST",  
            contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
            processData: false, // Not to process data  
            data: image,  
            success: function (result) {  
                alert(result);  
            },  
            error: function (err) {  
                alert(err.statusText);  
            }  
        });
```

where image is from a form with an input in it of type "file"

My C# is:

```
    [ActionName("Image")]
            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(List<IFormFile> files, Guid id)
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
```

The problem is that "files" is empty and "file" gives me the error "Incorrect Content-Type: image/png"

StackTrace [string]:"   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()"

Comment: What browser are you testing in? What is the value of `image`? Please update your post the full stack trace of the exception that occurs? What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: What happens if you change `List<IFormFile> files` to `IFormFile file`?

Comment: @mjwills I'm testing in Chrome,
"image" is :
File {
  lastModified:1472820029401
  lastModifiedDate:Fri Sep 02 2016 05:40:29
  name:"normalIssues3.PNG"
  size:70606
  type:"image/png"
  webkitRelativePath:"" }

Comment: @mjwills changing to IFormFile still gives me null

Comment: You're uploading a single file, whereas `List<IFormFile>` is a list, so you should upload a 1-element array of files instead. Also please confirm that you're using `multipart/form-data` instead of a "raw" file upload which this also looks like.

Comment: @Dai I've switched the `data: image` to `data: [image]` and now the error is: `Message [string]:"Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` and my form has the following on it:
`<form name="files" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple ...>`
and the inner input looks like:
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" ...>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem once and my solution was to bind the upload mechanism to a ViewModel. In this way I was able to upload a file to server with additional parameters (in your case the guid you're passing to the url). 
To do this I first created a view model

```
public class UploadImageViewModel
{
    public IFormFile file {get;set;}
    public Guid uniqueId {get;set;}
}
```

and used this in my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(UploadImageViewModel model)
{    
     //Here I can access my file and my Guid       
     var file = model.file; 
     Guid id = model.uniqueId;    
}
```

in my jquery calls I then passed a model instead of a single (or multiple) file:

```
var dataModel = new FormData();
dataModel.append('file', document.getElementById("YOUR-FILEUPLOAD-FIELD-ID").files[0]);
dataModel.append('uniqueId', guid);      
$.ajax({
        url: '/Provider/Image/' + guid,  
        type: "POST",  
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data  
        data: image,  
        success: function (result) {  
            alert(result);  
        },  
        error: function (err) {  
            alert(err.statusText);  
        }  
    });
```

Comment: How did you get the "image" from the form? When I try this the ViewModel's properties just end up null

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a step.... to retrieve the file and send to server controller you need to create a javascript object FormData. So the definition of the dataModel to send with your ajax post is: `var dataModel = new FormData(); dataModel.append('file', document.getElementById("imageUpload").files[0]); dataModel.append('uniqueId', guid); ` in this way your model inside the controller is populated. I also noticed that you have to retrieve the file with plain js and not jQuery in order to work